# SQL query for below table

Tags: sql-server

I have a table like this.  Id1 and Id2 are the reference of Id column

```
Id      Name     Id1     Id2    
1          X      3       4    
2          Y      2       1    
3          Z      4       2    
4          P      1       3
```

I need Output like this

```
Id      Name     Id1     Id2    
1          X      Z       P    
2          Y      Y       X    
3          Z      P       Y    
4          P      X       Z
```

Can some one help me to write a query using joins only

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Have you tried any query yet ? @pramod

Comment: Self join your table by using aliases: `SELECT t1.id, t1.name, t2.name, t3.name FROM yourtable t1 inner join yourtable as t2 on t1.id1 = t2.id inner join yourtable as t3 on t1.id2 = t3.id;`

Comment: Thanks Jnevill.. Can you please explain me why we have to use t1.id1 = t2.id and t1.id2 = t3.id like this. I tried with this I got wrong out put   t1.id = t2.id1 and t1.id = t3.id2. is there any difference . Here my question is we are using equal symbol so there is no difference right? whether we are using right side or left side

Comment: What does "Here my question is we are using equal symbol so there is no difference right? whether we are using right side or left side " mean???

Comment: Why we need to do like this t1.id1 = t2.id and t1.id2 = t3.id  instead of this  t1.id = t2.id1 and t1.id = t3.id2..How 1st one is different from second. Here my table t1 and t2 is same right?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT * INTO #Tbl1
FROM (VALUES    
(1       ,'  X     ',3     , 4),
(2       ,'  Y     ',2     , 1),
(3       ,'  Z     ',4     , 2),
(4       ,'  P     ',1     , 3))
x(Id     ,Name,Id1     ,Id2)

SELECT t.id, t.Name, t1.Name, t2.Name
FROM #Tbl1 as t
INNER JOIN #Tbl1 as t1 ON t.Id1 = t1.Id
INNER JOIN #Tbl1 as t2 ON t.Id2 = t2.Id
```

Comment: I am getting wrong output

Comment: Corrected the query

Comment: Thanks Slava.. Can you please explain me why we have to use t1.id1 = t2.id and t1.id2 = t3.id like this. I tried with this I got wrong out put t1.id = t2.id1 and t1.id = t3.id2. is there any difference . Here my question is we are using equal symbol so there is no difference right? whether we are using right side or left side

Comment: t- is an alias for the original sequence with "id", t1 & t2 are aliases for sequences with referenced id1 & id2.
BTW, there is no t3 in my example.